# Why might this voltage regulator have a resistor across the supply voltage?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, circuit-design, power-electronics, schematics

I have come across the schematic below, and I am unsure why there is a resistor across VIN to GND on the AP2205 5V voltage regulator. Why might this be?

Note: This is for an isolated CAN circuit where the CAN transceiver draws it's power from the CANBUS.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: It looks quite strange - particularly the 1% specification but that might be a default on the drawing package. It might be required to discharge the capacitors when powered down.

Comment: The data sheet shows a resistor in series with a cap to control startup time, but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: The interesting thing about random schematics of unknown origin is that these might be simply incorrect.

Comment: Yes I saw that in the datasheet, but that doesn't apply here as you say. It could be capacitor discharge.

Comment: Could be incorrect... but could be correct! I appreciate the input from all.

Comment: Since **not_enable** input **low** is only 0.4V, the resistor might simply be a pull-down resistor....but why 1%? It may also serve to shorten or eliminate oscillation during power-down...there *might* be strange interactions between not_enable and VIN (or VOUT).

Comment: @glen_geek you may be right ... there may have been a switch between Vin and EN' ... someone removed the switch and left the resistor